# How to align element with Flatlist in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I'm rendering messages in react-native and actually I want to make a visual structure as a typical chats(where a textinput aligned in bottom and messages go to top)

But I dont know exactly how to do it in React-Native, 
Here is how it looks https://ibb.co/muJino

and here is my code:

```
<View>

                <View style={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Message"
                        onChangeText={Message => this.setState({message: Message})}
                    />
                    <Button title="Send"/>
                </View>


                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.chats}
                    renderItem={this._renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                />

</View>
```

How I can do the styling as I want? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys I found the solution myself. Sometimes we need to think easy, so i used position : 'absolute' and now it stays as I Want.

```
<View style={{position: 'absolute', width: "100%", backgroundColor: 'beige', bottom: 0}}>
       <TextInput
              placeholder="Message"
              onChangeText={Message => this.setState({message: Message})}
         />
      <Button title="Send"/>
</View>
```

https://ibb.co/gTjD58

Comment: setting a static number for marginTop may causes problem in deferent device. its better to not to use absolute positioning except critical situation.

Comment: Instead of `marginTop: 440` try with `bottom: 0`. It's safer.

Comment: OK, will check it :) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah bottom: 0 worked and looks much safer, thank you tarik!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to stick the `TextInput` to the bottom of screen and the `FlatList` to top of the screen:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     <FlatList data={this.data}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return (
                  <Text>{item}</Text>
              )
          }} 
     />
     <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Button title={'send'} onPress={() => { }} />
          <TextInput style={{ flex: 1, borderWidth: 1 }} />
     </View>
</View>
```

I hope it will help.

**EDIT:**

for absolute positioning, its better to set position dynamically like this:

```
<View style={{position: 'absolute', width: "100%", backgroundColor: 'beige', marginTop: (Dimensions.get('window').height - 60) }}>
   <TextInput
          style={{height:30}}
          placeholder="Message"
          onChangeText={Message => this.setState({message: Message})}
     />
  <Button style={{height:30}} title="Send"/>
```

(I did not check the code, change numbers if they are not accurate)

Comment: i'm wondering why its not work for you! flex:1 for container view makes TextInput sticks to bottom and FlatList sticks to top for me

Comment: I dont know mate but I found the solution , you can check it also.

Comment: take a look at my edit. use Dimensions to set dynamic margin. have a nice code :)

Answer (score 0):

To have the text input at the bottom, simply place it after the FlatList.

```
<View>
    <FlatList/>
    <TextInput/>
</View>
```

Comment: In that case he would have to scroll all the way down in order to see the input. What he has to do is position the input as absolute, and stick it to the bottom of the screen. I will create an example if get some time.

Comment: yeah exactly.. :/